# Error in finding the package

Tags: ros, ros-package-path, environment

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi..
For following command:
**echo $ROS_PACKAGE_PATH**

Output: **/opt/ros/electric/stacks**

Change directory: **cd ~/ros_workspace**

Then: **roscreate-pkg beginner_tutorials std_msgs rospy roscpp**

**WARNING: current working directory is not on ROS_PACKAGE_PATH!
Please update your ROS_PACKAGE_PATH environment variable.** *I don't know why??*

How do I change it? I follow all the instruction in previous section of setting environmental variable where I get proper output as mentioned. But i think there is still something very basic going wrong, which I am not able to figure out..because I am new at Ubuntu.

After package is created, when i try to find: **rospack find beginner_tutorials**

message : rospack couldn't find beginner_tutorials.

I am getting this error from long time..and not able to find the solution!! Please help.
Is it possible for real time help?(on gmail, yahoo, skype..etc)

Thank you.
Regards.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12290/error-in-finding-the-package/) by [dbs12](https://answers.ros.org/users/1469/dbs12/) on ROS Answers with karma: 26 on 2011-12-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You need to add your ros_workspace to your ROS_PACKAGE_PATH. This can be done in your bashrc file. For a short, one-line solution enter the following into the commandline:

```
echo -e "\nexport ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=~/ros_workspace:$ROS_PACKAGE_PATH\n" >> ~/.bashrc
```

Then, in order to see the changes, you must remember to source your bashrc. (This only needs to be done on any terminals already open. Any new terminals you open henceforth will already be all set.)

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

---

Originally posted by [DimitriProsser](https://answers.ros.org/users/635/dimitriprosser/) with karma: 11163 on 2011-12-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1